# Writing complex structure to memory-mapped-file

Tags: c#, struct, memory-mapped-files

I try to write following struct to a memory mapped file, but I still have problem with the array (writing throws exception that the struct can not contain reference)

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
struct IndexEntry {
    [FieldOffset(0)]
    public byte key;

    [FieldOffset(4)]
    public int lastValueIdx;

    [FieldOffset(8)]
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = Constants.PART_ENTRY_SIZE)]
    public long[] values;
}
```

I use this calling for writing:

```
UnmanagedMemoryAccessor.Write<IndexEntry>(0, ref entry);
```

Can you please tell me, what am I doing wrong? Thx

Comment: Have you tried `public fixed long values[Constants.PART_ENTRY_SIZE / 8];`. Your struct has to be `unsafe` though.

Comment: I'll try but how will I access the array values then? And why the size is divided by 8?

Comment: One `long` = 8 bytes. And you would access them normally? `.values[0] = 15;` One downside is that there's no range check, so you can do `.values[100000] = 15;`.

Comment: Converting that array requires the kind of plumbing that's built into the pinvoke marshaller.  Also exposed as Marshal.StructureToPtr().  It was *intentionally* omitted from UnmanagedMemoryAccessor, it is too slow, it will only memcpy() structures.  You'll have to use WriteArray() or the *fixed* keyword.  Otherwise the basic reason why MMFs are not a fantastic tool in .NET, they generally only work decently in a language that treats pointers as first class citizens.  Like C++/CLI btw.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen OK, but when I try to write `this.values[this.lastValueIdx++] = value;`, it tells me "You cannot use fixed size buffers contained in unfixed expressions. Try using the fixed statement." Why?

Comment: See the comment @HansPassant made for why arrays won't work, I don't usually use fixed/unsafe code so I don't know why it won't work. It was a guess at the top of my head, nothing more.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen I made it to work thanks to the _fixed_ :-) Thank you, please make an answer so I can accept it

Comment: It is better if you type up the answer yourself since it seemed you didn't get it working to begin with and to me it now sounds like you changed the code somewhat? If so, you're in the best position to type up a good answer for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution of this is using the fixed size array and unsafe code. So the struct should look like this:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
unsafe struct IndexEntry {
    [FieldOffset(0)]
    public byte key;

    [FieldOffset(1)]
    public int lastValueIdx;

    [FieldOffset(5)]
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = Constants.PART_ENTRY_SIZE)]
    public fixed long values[Constants.PART_ENTRY_SIZE];
}
```

Note that the program (or a single project containing that struct) must be compiled with the "/unasfe" option and the array must be then accessed like this:

```
fixed(long* arr = this.values) {
    // Setting value
    arr[index] = value;
}
unsafe {
    // Getting value
    x = obj.values[index];
}
```

Then the `UnmanagedMemoryAccessor.Write<T>(...)` and `UnmanagedMemoryAccessor.Read<T>(...)` functions work perfectly.